# What is a "positive statement" in mathematical proof?

Tags: proof-writing, terminology, definition

I'm going through How to Prove It: A Structured Approach by Daniel J. Velleman and some terms that I frequently see are "positive statement" and "negative statement". I'm not sure what these are referring to and when I research the terms I can't seem to find definitions that relate to mathematical proof.

If you were tasked with defining these terms, how would you define them?

https://ibb.co/ykcv8KL

Comment: In this context it sounds like he's just using "negative statement" informally to mean a statement that is written with a negation at the start and "positive statement" to mean one that is not.  (There is a more technical notion of "positive formula" that is sometimes used in logic but I doubt he is talking about that.)

Comment: Are you familiar with [negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation)?

Comment: I suspected that, but I wasn't entirely sure if that was the case. Thank you.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey is right: "negative statement" is being used here to mean a statement that is written with a $\neg$ at the start.  To put it more informally, it is a statement that says that something _isn't_ the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, it seems that a negative statement is a proposition that comes with a logic negation in front of it. Let me try to explain it with an example, that should be clearer:

Positive statement: “There exists a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ such that $f(x)$ is constant on $X$“

Negative statement: “There does not exist a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ such that $f(x)$ is constant on $X$“, that logically means “for every function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, $f(x)$ is not constant on $X$ (that is there exists at least an $a$ and $b$ both in $X$ such that $f(a) \neq f(b)$.